# Inner DIVs wrapping in split pane scenario (with jQueryUI resizable)

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

Inspired by examples found on the internet based on jQueryUI resizable, I am trying to go further and nest some DIVs into the split pane but, as soon as I add a nested div, the right side wraps to the next line.

HTML:-

```
<div id="splitter">
  <div id="one">
    <!--div id="nested" /-->
  </div>
  <div id="two" />
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#splitter {
  width: calc(100% - 2*10px);
  height: calc(100% - 2*10px);
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
}

#one, #two {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 90%;
  min-width: 10%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  background: orange;
}

#two {
  background: green;
}

#nested {
  width: calc(100% - 2*3px);
  height: calc(100% - 2*3px);
  margin: 3px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: black;
}
```

JavaScript (OnLoad):-

```
$(function () {
  var innerDiv1 = $('#one');
  innerDiv1.resizable({
    handles: 'e',
    resize: function(event, ui) {
      var parent = $('#splitter');
      var child1 = $('#one');
      var child2 = $('#two');
      var parent_width = parent.width();
      var child1_width = child1.outerWidth(true);
      var child2_width = parent_width - child1_width - (child2.outerWidth(true) - child2.width()) - 1;
      child2.outerWidth(child2_width);
    }
  });
});
```

results:-

- before inner DIV: https://jsfiddle.net/ju1enzhc/2/
- after inner DIV: https://jsfiddle.net/ju1enzhc/4/

What do I need to add/change in order to have the split pane work properly also when content is added to it?

Comment: The problem is not connected with the Split Pane functionality but it rather seems to be a pure CSS problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using outer flexbox instead of inner floats: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgwtn0nk/7/

```
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#splitter {
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  height: calc(100% - 6px);
  padding:3px;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#one,
#two {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 90%;
  min-width: 10%;
  background: orange;
}

#two {
  background: green;
}

#nested {
  width: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 6px);
  margin:3px;
  background: black;
}
```